# How to display toaster message in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am developing Angularjs Application. I am trying to display Toaster messages in my angular controller. I refereed http://angular-js.in/angular-toastr/. I am facing below issue. I am not able to call success,info etc notification from controller and i am getting annot read property 'success' of undefined error. I have tried as below.

In index.html i have added below code.

```
<!--Toaster-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css" />
    <!--Toaster-->
```

this is my main.js

```
var app = angular.module('RoslpApp', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.router', 'toastr']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
 //ui-routing states here});

app.controller('RoslpAppController', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate, toastr) {
    toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');
    $scope.clickHandler = function (key) {

        $translate.use(key);
    };
}]);
```

May I know why I am facing issues here? any help would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `toastr` as string dependency to the controller.

change this

```
app.controller('RoslpAppController', ['$scope', '$translate',function ($scope, $translate, toastr) {
```

to this

```
app.controller('RoslpAppController', ['$scope', '$translate','toastr',function ($scope, $translate, toastr) {
```

Comment: I am using ui routing so Everytime do i need to pass toaster in parent controller as dependency? –

Comment: if you want to use the toaster inside the parent controller you need to pass it as a dependancy

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `toastr` in controller definition.

```
app.controller('RoslpAppController', ['$scope', '$translate','toastr', function ($scope, $translate, toastr) {
```

Comment: I am using ui routing so Everytime do i need to pass toaster in parent controller as dependency?

Comment: You need pass toaster in controller, in which you are using toaster.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script Src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/css/toastr.css">

 <script>
  var app=angular.module("myapp", []);
  app.controller("namesctrl", function($scope){

   $(function () {
    $('#error').click(function () {
        // make it not dissappear
        toastr.error("Noooo oo oo ooooo!!!", "Title", {
         "timeOut": "0",
         "extendedTImeout": "0"
        });
    });
    $('#info').click(function () {
     // title is optional
     toastr.info("Info Message", "Title");
    });
    $('#warning').click(function () {
     toastr.warning("Warning");
    });
    $('#success').click(function () {
     toastr.success("YYEESSSSSSS");
    });
   });


  });

  
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="namesctrl">
 <input type="button" value="Error" id="error" />
 <input type="button" value="Info" id="info" />
 <input type="button" value="Warning" id="warning" />
 <input type="button" value="Success" id="success" />
 <br><br><br><br>
 See official example: <a href='http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html' target='blank'>Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```